# JQuery menu showing a box

Tags: jquery, menu

I am learning the basics of JQuery, the menu() shown by my instructor doesn't look like mine at all.

### Here's the LAF of the menu I created:

[image]

### Code:

```html
<!Doctype HTML>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <ul id="greetings">
   <li>
    Hello
    <ul>
     <li>Hi</li>
     <li>Welcome</li>
    </ul>
   </li>

   <li>World!</li>
  </ul>

  <script>
   $(function() {
    $('#greetings').menu()
   })
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Another question:
[JQuery Menu Not Working Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390267/jquery-menu-not-working-correctly#16390300)

The solution didn't work with my code at all... Even if I add nested lists, it doesn't work. When I hover on the box, the cursor changes to pointer, and clicking the box creates another tiny box from the left.

Browsers tried:

- Firefox
- Chromium
- Falkon

---

How to get the menu working?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to try something more along the lines of what the documentation suggests.

https://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-menus

```
<ul id="greetings">
  <li>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Hi</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Welcome</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>World</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, your code is missing the < in the First div tag (Hello). Anyway, that worked but I also needed to use display property with inline-block values to get it working!